# kafka-streams instance on startup continuously logs "Found no committed offset for partition traces-1"

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka-streams app with 2 instances. This is a brand new kafka-cluster with all topics created and have no messages written to them yet.

I start the first instance and see that it has transitioned from REBALANCING to RUNNING state

Now I start the next instance and notice that it continuously logs the following:

```
2020-01-14 18:03:57.896 [streaming-app-f2457059-c9ec-4c21-a177-be54f8d59cb2-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=streaming-app-f2457059-c9ec-4c21-a177-be54f8d59cb2-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=streaming-app] Found no committed offset for partition traces-1
```

Comment: have you solved this problem?